# Find an angle not on the circumference of a circle problem.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, angle

I know this has to be extremely easy but I'm not going to solve this problem.

The task is to find the angle at point $A$.

Thanks!

[image: Here is the image.]

Comment: Hint: you can erase the point $D$ and the two segments connected to it. You don't need to use that point. What's left is an example of a theorem you've probably seen already; and if you haven't seen it, there's still enough information to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\angle EOF+\angle BOC+49^\circ+175^\circ=360^\circ$. It follows that $\angle EOF+\angle BOC=136^\circ$.

$\angle OCA=\dfrac{180^\circ-\angle BOC}{2}$ and $\angle OEA=\dfrac{180^\circ-\angle EOF}{2}$ because $\triangle OBC$ and $\triangle OEF$ are isosceles respectively.

Now $\angle OAC+\angle OCA+\angle BOC+\angle BOA=180^\circ$ and $\angle OAE+\angle OEA+\angle EOF+\angle FOA=180^\circ$. Summing these two gives $$\begin{align}
(\angle OAC+\angle OAE)+\angle OCA+\angle OEA+(\angle BOC+\angle EOF)+(\angle BOA+\angle FOA)&=360^\circ\\
\angle EAC+\angle OCA+\angle OEA+136^\circ+49^\circ&=\\
\angle EAC+\frac{180^\circ-\angle BOC}{2}+\frac{180^\circ-\angle EOF}{2}+136^\circ+49^\circ&=\\
2\angle EAC+(180^\circ-\angle BOC)+(180^\circ-\angle EOF)+370&=720^\circ\\
2\angle EAC+360^\circ-(\angle BOC+\angle EOF)+370&=\\
2\angle EAC+360^\circ-136^\circ+370&=\\
2\angle EAC&=126^\circ\\
\angle EAC&=63^\circ
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

By [extended central angle theorem](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/geometrytriangleinscribedanglecircle2.aspx) the angle $A=(175^\circ- 49^\circ)/2=63^\circ $.

Comment: Why does this work? A isn't on the circle.

Comment: @ericw31415 See [secant angles](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/EMAT6680.2003.fall/Nichols/6690/Webpage/Day%207.htm).

Comment: @ericw31415 I have used the extended central angle theorem, which is applicable for arbitrary position of the intersection point of secants. I explicitly took into account the fact that the point lies _outside_ the circle. The [proof](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/geometrytriangleinscribedanglecircle2.aspx) of the extended central angle theorem is extremely simple.

Comment: @user I see now. At first you wrote inscribed angle theorem and that didn't match with what I learned

Comment: @ericw31415 I am quite sure that at the moment of your comment the name of the theorem was already corrected. I have learned in school the extended version of the theorem but was not sure about the English name for it.